# React custom hooks using refs as index counters

Tags: javascript, react.js

My custom hook `useTyper.js` ended up as a **bit of a mess** and hard to read.

It's mimicking a nested for-loop but using `React.useRef`s to hold on to the indexes between renders. The indexes are the current positions of the outer and inner loop, those often named `i` and `j` in traditional nested for loops.

Here's a [fancy code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-turing-obice) for the mess below.

One thing I'm particularly unhappy with is the naming of `stringIdx` and `stringsIdx`. Any suggestion for a change?

`useTyper.js`

```
import React from "react";
import useInterval from "./useInterval.js";

/**
 * A simple typewriter that prints strings, one character after another
 * @param {Array<string>} strings - Array of strings to type
 * @param {function<string>} set - A useState setter to update the current string value
 * @param {number} defaultDelay - Delay between updates
 */
const useTyper = (strings, set, defaultDelay = 100) => {
  const [delay, setDelay] = React.useState(defaultDelay);
  // index counters, normally named i and j if this were an imperative loop
  const stringIdx = React.useRef(0);
  const stringsIdx = React.useRef(0);

  const textTyper = () => {
    const currentString = strings[stringsIdx.current];

    set(currentString.substr(0, stringIdx.current + 1));

    if (stringIdx.current > currentString.length) {
      // Done with string
      stringsIdx.current += 1;
      stringIdx.current = 0;
      if (stringsIdx.current > strings.length - 1) {
        setDelay(null); // Ended.
      }
    }
    stringIdx.current += 1;
  };

  useInterval(textTyper, delay);
};

export default useTyper;
```

For completion, this is the `useInterval` hook being used by `useTyper`.
It can be referenced from [one of Dan Abramovs blog posts](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/).
`useInterval.js`

```
import React from 'react';

const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = React.useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(id);
      };
    }
  }, [delay]);
};

export default useInterval;
```

Here is how the `useTyper` hook can be used.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import useTyper from "./hooks/useTyper.js";
export default function App() {
  const [placeHolder, setPlaceHolder] = useState("");

  const placeHolders = [
    "First input suggestion",
    "Second input suggeston",
    "Creativity flows...   ",
    "Alright, lets leave it here."
  ];

  useTyper(placeHolders, setPlaceHolder);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <input
          id="formElement"
          autoComplete="off"
          autoFocus
          size="20"
          type="text"
          placeholder={placeHolder}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Again, here's the link to the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-turing-obice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to be fairly clean code.

## Suggestions

1. Use [string::slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) or [string::substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) versus [string::substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr). `substr` isn't deprecated but also isn't recommended for use.

> Warning: Although `String.prototype.substr(…)` is not strictly
> deprecated (as in "removed from the Web standards"), it is considered
> a **legacy function** and should be avoided when possible. It is not part
> of the core JavaScript language and may be removed in the future. If
> at all possible, use the `substring()` method instead.

```
setCurrentString(currentString.slice(0, currentStringIndex.current + 1));
```

2. Provide clearer parameter names, i.e. `stringArray` versus just `strings`, and `setString` or `setCurrentString` versus `set`. `set` alone can be confusing as it isn't very descriptive, i.e. "is it a mathematical set?" By naming a function with verbNoun it is clearer to a reader *what* it is *and* what it does.

```
const useTyper = (stringsArray, setCurrentString, defaultDelay = 100) => {
```

3. `stringIdx` and `stringsIdx` can cause mental gymnastics looking for the 's' to differentiate the two. Isolated from one another the names *aren't* terrible, but when used together within the same function it is more demanding. The names *should* also align closer to the variable they indicate an index for. Based on the previous parameter naming suggestion I recommend `stringArrayIndex` and `currentStringIndex`.
4. You also appear to do an extra iteration on the `currentString` with the conditional test `currentStringIndex.current > currentString.length`. You can increment to the next string when the current string's index is equal to the length, `currentStringIndex.current >= currentString.length`.
5. Similar conditional test for checking for the end of the strings array, when the index is. greater then *or equal* to the length you can quit. `stringArrayIndex.current >= stringArray.length`

```
const useTyper = (stringArray, setCurrentString, defaultDelay = 100) => {
  const [delay, setDelay] = React.useState(defaultDelay);
  // index counters, normally named i and j if this were an imperative loop
  const currentStringIndex = React.useRef(0);
  const stringArrayIndex = React.useRef(0);

  const textTyper = () => {
    const currentString = stringArray[stringArrayIndex.current];

    setCurrentString(currentString.slice(0, currentStringIndex.current + 1));

    if (currentStringIndex.current >= currentString.length) {
      // Done with string
      stringArrayIndex.current += 1;
      currentStringIndex.current = 0;
      if (stringArrayIndex.current >= stringArray.length) {
        setDelay(null); // Ended.
      }
    }
    currentStringIndex.current += 1;
  };

  useInterval(textTyper, delay);
};
```

Good job, nice hook.

Comment: Excellent feedback! I ended up with [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usetyper-after-codereview-civxs) with your exact suggestions, _but_: I removed the `+ 1` in the call to `setCurrentString` since it made the subsequent strings start with two characters printed instead of one.

Comment: @HenrikSN Ah, good catch, I hadn't noticed that and likely thought it was my machine. I hadn't messed with the timer delay at all.